# Pointers in linked list not working as expected

Tags: c++, linked-list

This realization of linked list is broken. Address of nodes[0].next doesn't match the nodes[1] address. So nodes[1].next is NULL (as default value). I added some address  printing to the search method. It looks like the nodes[1] wasn't initialized?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef struct Node_T {
    int data;
    Node_T *next;
} Node;

class LinkedList{
    public:
        vector<Node> nodes;
            LinkedList(){
        }

        void insert(int data) {
            Node temp_node;
            temp_node.data = data;
            temp_node.next = NULL;

            size_t len = nodes.size();
            nodes.push_back(temp_node);
            if (len > 0) {
                nodes[len - 1].next = &nodes[len];
            }
        }

        int search(int val){
            if (nodes.empty())
                return -1;

            Node *node_ptr = &nodes[0];

            // Debug
            cout << &nodes[1] << "\n";
            cout << &nodes[0].next << "\n";

            int i = 0;
            do {
                if (node_ptr->data == val) return i;
                    i++;
            } while((node_ptr = node_ptr->next) != NULL);

            return -1;
        }

};

int main()
{
    LinkedList llist;
    llist.insert(1);
    llist.insert(2);
    llist.insert(3);
    llist.insert(4);
    llist.insert(5);
    cout << llist.search(3) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

It shows me: `0x8e6a060 0x8e6a05c -1`

Comment: Why don't you use the std::vector methods to simulate your linked list?

Comment: Why use vector when you have a linked list? And why use a linked list why you have vector?!

Comment: Umm, I done it for educational purposes))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Your printout is incorrect: this line

```
cout << &nodes[0].next << "\n";
```

prints the address of `next`, rather than printing the `next` itself. Changing to

```
cout << nodes[0].next << "\n";
```

gives the correct printout ([demo](http://ideone.com/JR1QdS)).

However, the main issue is that you keep pointers to elements of `std::vector`. These become invalid after the first write, because new storage gets allocated for the growing vector.

You can certainly work around this by reserving sufficient space upfront (call `nodes.reserve(1000)` from the constructor of your list; [demo](http://ideone.com/JR1QdS)) but that is merely a hack: you should use `new` and `delete` to allocate elements of your linked list manually. That is the whole point of this exercise.

> But I still need a container to ensure that nodes will be live as expected?

No, you do not. Your class *is* a container. By referencing the whole chain of nodes from the head pointer it can ensure that the entire chain is kept "live".

Answer (score 3):

When you add elements to a `vector`, references to (and hence addresses of) vector elements are invalidated. You must therefore not use values  such as `&nodes[0]` or `&nodes[len]`, as they are meaningless.

Comment: Ok. And thus there is no way to get address of vector element? Not for linked list, may I need this address in other cases?

Comment: @Zamony: you can get the address of an element at any one moment, but the address is not valid once you change the vector. In particular, you can't store a element's address permanently in some `next` field.

Comment: Alright, so the solution is to use a vector of pointers then.

Answer (score 3):

The point with an exercise like this is to get the hang of the internal structure in a linked list.  You have replaced that internal structure with a `vector<Node>`.

Instead of a vector, the idea is to have a

```
private:
    Node* head;
```

As you data member.

In your insert function you are supposed to dynamically allocate memory for the Node with

```
Node* newNodePointer = new Node;
```

And manipulate the pointer with next and such.

It is worth to point out, that this is fine as an exercise, but your "real" code should use standard library facilities.

Comment: But I still need a container to ensure that nodes will be live as expected?